# css menu with dropdown li width

Tags: html, css, list, menu

when I set the "width" attribute of the .topMenu li, the .subMenu width is too narrow, even though I set it's position to absolute. It also is horizontal instead of vertical. Why?

the html

```
    <div id="navigation">
            <ul id="navBlock">
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li class="topMenu">
                    ABOUT US
                    <ul class="subMenu">
                        <li>WELCOME</li>
                        <li>HISTORY</li>
                    </ul>   
                </li>
         </ul>      
    </div>
```

the css

```
#navBlock{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;    
     list-style-type: none;  
}
#navBlock li{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    border:1pt solid #ccc;
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
#navBlock li:hover{ 
    cursor:pointer;
    background:orange;  
}
.topMenu:hover .subMenu{
    display:block;      
    position:absolute;
}   
.subMenu{
    display:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;             
}
.subMenu li{
    border:1pt solid #aaa;
    background:#fff;        
    width:200px;        
    display: inline; 
    position:absolute;
}
.subMenu li:hover{
    float:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L28Lf3se/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of specificity. Your CSS for `.subMenu li` is being overridden by the `#navMenu li` because it thinks it's more specific. That whole block isn't being used. Re-label the `.subMenu li` to `#navBlock li ul li` and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Change the width in px than %

```
#navBlock li{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    border:1pt solid #ccc;
    width:150px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
```

Everything will work smooth

Comment: This answer may produce the desired result but the reason it wasn't working in the first place was because that whole block is being overriden.

Answer (score 1):

`#navBlock li`(0-1-0-1) more specific than `.subMenu li`(0-0-1-1) that's why the width you set for `.subMenu li` are get overrided.
You shouldn't touch your `#navBlock li` width.
Change `#navBlock li` to `#navBlock>li` and magic will happen.
This is best you can do to solve your problem.